# Duplicate row in Seed Initializer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I'm working on an application using ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework (Code First).
I have a problem duplicating entries in the database - and I expected that the data in the database will be supplemented only when they are deleted (and after migration).

I have model:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in DAL folder MyContext.cs:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public MyContext() : base("MyContext") 
    { }
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new MyInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And in DAL folder MyInitializer.cs:

```
public class MyInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>
{
    public static void SeedMyData(MyContext context)
    {
        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category() { CategoryId = 1, Name = "asd1" },
            new Category() { CategoryId = 2, Name = "asd2" }
        };
        categories.ForEach(x => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(x));
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And in Migrations folder Configuration.cs.cs:

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyApp.DAL.MyContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "MyApp.DAL.MyContext";
    }
    protected override void Seed(MyApp.DAL.MyContext context)
    {
        MyInitializer.SeedMyData(context);
    }
}
```

Every time when I run app - row are duplicated.
id 39   asd1,
id 40   asd2,
id 41   asd1,
id 42   asd2,
id 43   asd1,
id 44   asd2,

Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you haven't already inserted those rows. Use LINQ and [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) method, also I would suggest to simply use a `foreach` loop which is more preferable and recommended than `ForEach` method:

```
foreach (var item in categories)
{
    if (!context.Categories.Any(c => c.CategoryId == item.CategoryId))
    {
        context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(item);
    }
}
```